# Javascript does not recognize node when I use append child to append a string

Tags: javascript, dom

I am playing around with DOM commands to get a better understanding of them. However, I am getting an error message when I try to append a string of HTML to a child of an element I've selected. I get an error message that says my div3 variable is not a node. However, when I console.log(div3) it is listed as a node in my console log. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');
div3.innerHTML = "Test String";
console.log(div3);

div3.appendChild("<h2>myH2 tag</h2>")
```

```html
<div id="div3"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, natus.</p></div>
```

Comment: It's not about div3, it's about the fact that you're passing a string, as opposed to a node to `appendChild()`

Comment: _<h2>myH2 tag</h2>_ is not a **Node**, it's a string/text. You can read up on the topic [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Comment: @MarcHjorth Please [don't link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com); use official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: @ChrisG Personally, I believe the W3 docs are easier to understand for newcomers than the official docs - especially this one regarding appending a child. But I will keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're getting the same error message as me, it is the following:

> VM189:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
> parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

This is because `"<h2>myH2 tag</h2>"` is not a node.

If you want to append a tag like that you'll have to create a node from scratch, and then append it:

```js
// your code:
var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');
div3.innerHTML = "Test String";

// new:
const newNode = document.createElement('h2')

newNode.innerText = "myH2 tag"

div3.appendChild(newNode)
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need convert div3 variable for DomElement use this: `div3 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(div3, "text/xml");` before call appendChild()

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that youo're trying to pass a string to the appendChild function - it needs to be of Node Type. You could pass the tags inside of innerHTML instead along with the content but the snippet I added gives you an idea of how to go abut it.

MDN link for appendChild - MDN is our friend:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.my-body');
let header = document.createElement('h2');
// insert content into the header we created above
header.innerHTML = 'This is some heading text';
// append header to the container
parent.appendChild(header);
```

```html
<div class="my-body"></div>
```